# Magento: adding a block to 'admin/sales_order_create/index' page

Tags: magento, layout, e-commerce

I have been trying to add a custom block to 'admin/sales_order_create/index' page with limited success.

The custom block does not show up after i choose a customer or clicking "create new customer".  But when I refresh the page after the order loads, my custom block shows up.

I added the custom block with the following XML:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
    <reference name="data">
        <block type="fflshipment/adminhtml_orderlocator" name="order_ffl_locator" template="fflshipment/create_order_address.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Look again at the sales.xml file, as well as an `adminhtml_sales_order_create_index` handle there is an `adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data` handle further down, this is sometimes loaded by AJAX. Your layout needs to modify both handles equally.